# Change structure from array of string to deep array

Tags: go, struct

I’ve the following structure which I created manually the values like `app service runner etc`

```
func Cmr(mPath string) [][]string {
    cav := [][]string{
        {mPath, "app", "app2"},
        {mPath, "service"},
        {mPath, "runner1", "runner2", "runner3"},
    }
    return cav
}
```

Now I need from this input to create this struct, I mean to return the same structure   ‘cav`

Now I’ve other function which returns `array of string` name `cmdList`
each line have a **space delimite**r  between values like `app app2 appN`

```
0 = app app2
1 = service
2 = runner1 runner2 runner3
```

How can I take the above array of string and put it as parameter to the function `Cmr` 
And **remove the hard-coded** value and get them from the `cmdList` instead of hard-coded them...

Like

```
func Cmr(mPath string,cmdList []string) [][]string {
    cav := [][]string{
        {mPath, cmdList[0], "app2"},
        {mPath, "service"},
        {mPath, "runner1", "runner2", "runner3"},
    }
    return cav
}
```

**update** 
at the end it should be something like this **except** the I dont know how to split the entry of the `cmdList` with the space delimiter

```
func Cmr(mPath string, cmdList []string) [][]string {
    cav := [][]string{}

    cav = append(cav, append([]string{mPath}, cmdList[0]))
    cav = append(cav, append([]string{mPath}, cmdList[1]))
    cav = append(cav, append([]string{mPath}, cmdList[2]))

    return cav
}
```

This will create something like (since Im not handling the space delimiter)

```
   cav := [][]string{
        {mPath, "app app2"},
        {mPath, "service"},
        {mPath, "runner1 runner2 runner3"},
    }
```

**But I need**

```
  cav := [][]string{
        {mPath, "app", "app2"},
        {mPath, "service"},
        {mPath, "runner1", "runner2", "runner3"},
    }
```

Comment: Please `go fmt` your code, post a minimal but complete example and use the right kind of quotes in your code.

Comment: @gonutz - done please have a look

Comment: I edited your answer to use the standard indentation and the `"` quote character everywhere. However it is not clear to me what you are asking. Please try to explain it more precisely. Can you give another code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you're looking for something like:

```
cav = append(cav, strArray)
```

where `strArray` is the array of strings you've received from `cmdList()`

**EDIT:** this ended up being what they were looking for: https://play.golang.org/p/ZFFhRRu43Em

Comment: Thank you, can you please add more context ?

Comment: based on your other comments, it seems like you're expecting cmdList to be an array of arrays of strings? maybe what you want is
`for i := 0; i < len(cmdList); i++ {
    cav = append(cav, cmdList[i]
}` its hard to tell without the calling context and/or what you're expecting the output to be.

Comment: yes something like this, can you please edit your answer with the new suggestion and Ill try it

Comment: in addition I've a space speration between each array instance like `app` and `app2` there is space between , and for each other line

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you provide an example?

Comment: think that each line in the `cmdList` have space delimiter (array postion 0 is `app app2 appN` etc )  and at the end each entry in cav should be like .`{mPath, "app", "app2","appN"},`

Comment: is it more clean now ?

Comment: Oh I see. What you want is something like this:
 `for i := 0; i < len(cmdList); i++ { 
cav = append(cav, strings.Split(cmdList[i]," "))
}`

Comment: Please see my update in the question , is it more clear now ?

Comment: Btw, it will be great if you can update this https://play.golang.org/p/Oc6SBeLCPus and your answer ?

Comment: Sorry Im not able to make it work, can you please update this https://play.golang.org/p/Oc6SBeLCPus and share it ?

Comment: Thanks you 1+ for support :), just one issue :) instead of this `[[1234 app app2] [1234 service] [1234 runner1 runner2 runner3]]` it should be like this `[[1234, app, app2] [1234 ,service] [1234 , runner1 , runner2 , runner3]]` with `,` between the entries

Comment: Well that's just the way that fmt.Println() happens to display arrays. If you really want commas between the entries, you can add them yourself with something like: https://play.golang.org/p/ZFFhRRu43Em

Answer (score 0):

Basically from what I see it seems you should be getting those string slices by argument, and append them to your `[][]string`.

Here is a complete example, where they are passed to the function:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Cmr(mPath string, appList, serviceList, runnerList []string) [][]string {
    cav := [][]string{}
    cav = append(cav, append([]string{mPath}, appList...))
    cav = append(cav, append([]string{mPath}, serviceList...))
    cav = append(cav, append([]string{mPath}, runnerList...))

    return cav
}

func main() {
    cmr := Cmr(
        "mpathTestValue",
        []string{"app1", "app2"},
        []string{"service1", "service2"},
        []string{"runner1", "runner2", "runner3"},
    )

    for _, values := range cmr {
        fmt.Println(values)
    }
}
```

Gives the output

```
[mpathTestValue app1 app2]
[mpathTestValue service1 service2]
[mpathTestValue runner1 runner2 runner3]
```

You can try playing with it yourself [here](https://play.golang.org/p/-5GEiJ-g871)

Comment: thank you , this is close what I need except that `appList, serviceList, runnerList` is one array of string `cmd list` which contains all

Comment: If you have one slice that contains all of them, how do you plan to make the difference between the strings that should go in the first slice, the second slice and the third slice?

Comment: each entry is in new line, each line contain several values which should be sperated by space

Comment: cmd list contain `0 = app app2
1 = service
2 = runner1 runner2 runner3 `

Comment: Please see that I've a space speration between each line , app and app2 there is space between , and for each other line  . this is what makes it a bit more complicated